# How to configure haskell cradle when I use cabal?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have read the official documentation of cradle . But when I follow the instructions in the documentation , there is a error .

```
Failed to parse result of calling cabal

cabal: Internal error in target matching. It should always be possible to find
a syntax that's sufficiently qualified to give an unambiguous match. However
when matching 'lib:hie-bios' we found lib:hie-bios (unknown-component) which
does not have an unambiguous syntax. The possible syntax and the targets they
match are as follows:
'lib:hie-bios' which matches lib:hie-bios (unknown-component),
:pkg:lib:lib:lib:file:hie-bios (unknown-file)
```

Answer (score 1):

(update 2021-11-12): now upstream fixed a lot of stuff & it is all expected to "just work" without need.

Just yesterday (2021-11-11) I talked with HLS folks & contributed documentation updates on the situation to HLS docs.

Check - if you have `hie.yaml` & `hie.yml` remnants in repo, backup * delete them & check the clean run.

If clean run is unsuccessful:

Use [implicit-hie](http://%20https://hackage.haskell.org/package/implicit-hie)'s `gen-hie`.

Oversimplifying: `implicit-gie` - is a project that HLS & fellows use internally to detect configuration. So if implicit configuration detection does not work - running a generator directly allows to overcome middleman lsp-chain generation issues. In most cases that helps by itself. Having configuration explicitly - makes it tangible to check what is going on (configuration is largely self-explanatory) & compare with documentation.

Majority of cases are covered by generator, even complex nontraditional monorepo cases. Nix results of course may vary (since Nix allows infinite number of ways to do stuff). And in any case - the tool helps with the syntax and configuration of cradles.

Note that tool currently determines the cradle by looking at the build directories present (`dist-newstyle`, `.stack-work`)